# How can I send 3 emails? before due date, on due date and after due date if status is not completed

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-server, workflow, designer-workflow, email

How can I create a workflow using SharePoint designer 2010 to send 3 emails? before due date, on due date and after due date if status not completed.

Comment: Someone pls help

Answer (score 0):

Hello you can edit behaviour of Workflow Task when you click on it. [Manual and examples here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/use-the-task-process-editor-for-approval-workflows-8680b4a4-36b1-441c-b070-e515976078aa). [Some info here too](https://www.rightpoint.com/thought/2012/04/17/sharepoint-designer-2010-workflow-advanced-properties.aspx).

If you need more examples just google: SharePoint Workflow 2010 task behaviour

*Hope it helps!*

Answer (score 0):

You can follow the workflow steps below to send emails at the relevant time. Modify the before due date and after due date, and change if condition with your own task.

[image]